# Creating a local notification to fire at a specific time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I need my application to store some `local notifications` that should be launched on a specific time.

My application is simple. The user can book times using a `UIDatePicker`. The notification is to be fired 2 minutes before that booked time.

For now i am trying to manually insert a time that the notification should be fired at. I am using this code:

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()

self.timePicked = " 22:38:00 +0000"

timeForLocalPush = defaults.objectForKey("timeForLocalPush") as! String

timeForLocalPush = timeForLocalPush + self.timePicked

print(timeForLocalPush)  // this prints for this example today, 2016-08-30 22:38:00 +0000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYY-MM-dd"

notification.fireDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeForLocalPush)
notification.timeZone = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().timeZone
notification.alertBody = self.nameField.text! + " Har bokat tid nu!"


UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

What happens is that the notification is fired instantly after booking the time. Desired action is this:

Current Time: 14:17

Client books for this time: 15:00

Local notification is set to be fired: 14:58

If you need any additional information just tell me. Thank you

Comment: what is the output of dateFormatter.dateFromString(timeForLocalPush)? make sure it is not nil.

Comment: It was nil, hmm why does this happen and what can  i do to fix it? @Sujit

Comment: Your date formatter is wrong. Use "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initially check your date format it is in wrong `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYY-MM-dd"`, it is in `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

for e.g

```
let localNotification1 = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification1.alertBody = "Your alert message "
    localNotification1.timeZone = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().timeZone
     let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    localNotification1.fireDate = formatter.dateFromString("2016-08-30 22:38:00")


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set your date format proper:

```
// this prints for this example today, 2016-08-30 22:38:00 +0000

//Your date format decalre:     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYY-MM-dd"

 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```