# How to schedule and repeat local notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, local

I'm trying to make an application to help quitting smoking,

I need the user to enter his first cigarette time, and the time between each cigarette , and finally the added time to increase time between each cigarette. and at this time I send a local notification.

Ex: let say his first cigarette at 7:00 AM and he smokes 1 cigarette every 1 Hr and he want to add extra 10 min.

so 1st cigarette : 7:00 
2nd : 8:10/
3rd : 9:20/
4th :10:30 .. etc

I tried a lot of solutions but I have some problems about date format that I got from picker views, I need them to be like "hh:MM a"

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227325/creating-a-local-notification-to-fire-at-a-specific-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227325/creating-a-local-notification-to-fire-at-a-specific-time)

Answer (score 0):

To get a date in a different format, you can create a NSDate from a Date object and then use NSDateFormatter to format:

```
let date=NSDate(timeInterval: 0, since: yourDate)
let dateFormatter=DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("hh:mm a")
String dateString=dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

You can get the initial date object from the UIDatePicker or when it changes and a method is called in its delegate.

Answer (score 0):

> first create a date object with

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600) // it may be any date whatever you want
```

> To create the trigger from the date components:

```
let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
```

> Now pass that date in UNCalendarNotificationTrigger with repeats true

```
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)
```

Create a date with time :

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
let someDateTime = formatter.date(from: "2016/10/08 22:31") // put your date and time here
```

> if Locale specific time :

```
 formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution suggested isn't elegant enough, so you have to create one notification for every hour, instead use this trigger

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (60*60) + (10*60), repeats: true)
```

60*60 being the hour you mentioned and 10*60 being the 10 minute, set repeating to true and viola, your notification now triggers every 70 minutes.